# What is the difference between Add-PSSnapin and Import-Module in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, pssnapin, import-module

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between Add-PsSnapIn and Import-Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038887/whats-the-difference-between-add-pssnapin-and-import-module)

What is the difference between `Add-PSSnapin` and `Import-Module` in PowerShell?

At the end, both seem like they provide the same result.

Which one is the recommended approach?

Comment: I recommend http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/.  No info on plugins, just modules, which IIUC are the recommended approach for everything except MS legacy code (like SQL plugin, and TFS plugin).

Comment: Clean and crisp - http://blogs.technet.com/b/aviraj/archive/2011/12/04/powershell-using-modules-and-snap-ins-what-s-the-difference-between-modules-amp-snap-ins.aspx

Answer (score 9):

**PsSnapins** are the old fashion way (existing inPowerShell V1) to add CmdLet or Providers (but still in use)

- They need to be registered (with installutil.exe tool)
- They are assemblies written in one of the .NET language

**Modules** are the new way (added in PowerShel V2) to add CmdLet or Providers

- They just have to be joinable on the file system (see $env:psmodulepath)
- They may be scripts written in PowerShell (for CmdLet only) or assemblies for CmdLet and Providers written with one of the .NET language
- It exists a manifest form that allow to specify much information about the creator, but also the dependancies on PowerShell versions, Framework version or other modules or assemblies version.

  I think that you can use module unless you have to support existing PowerShell V1 computers.